# OpenCV Mat bitwise_xor with randu()

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, encryption

Source Code: http://pastebin.com/LyBbNCm6

Example output from webcam:
[image: Example Output from Webcam]

First post on stackoverflow so hopefully I'm doing this right:

The question relates to C++/OpenCV.

Specifically: 
I'm trying to use opencv's randu() and bitwise_xor() to do the image equivalent of a "one time pad". I do understand that there are higher performance solutions to this problem which will not suffer the same image degradation & frame rate problems. I've also considered the problems that could be encountered with lossy compression in video codecs.

Apologies for the code quality:

-This is proof of concept code, so I didn't do anything to make it object oriented/take opportunities to turn repetitive code in to functions(I apologize in advance for the impact on readability).

-I tried to accurately comment line by line and section by section what the intended purpose of various chunks of code were. Some code is there because attempts to simplify the code and utilize memory more efficiently were unsuccessful for unknown reasons.

-I suspect the color space conversion to HSV was unnecessary but I had this code left over from a GPU accelerated "inRange()"-type implementation intended to segment the hue "red".

The end-goal is symmetric-key video encryption using uncompressed video of random noise as the shared key. It's a programming exercise I came up with for myself.

I've already played with AES(CBC) and was considering serializing the Mat for that purpose, but I really want to be able to view the encrypted images as video/image data(uncompressed).

An asymmetric key approach from an established code-base like "OpenSSH" would probably be a better decision from an encryption best-practices and key management perspective(but that is a different programming exercise than the one I'm practicing right now). As an example: I thought about piping an libav/ffmpeg stream through an SSH tunnel. Or various other options inside VPN, as well as looking at OpenSSL.

In terms of doing things weird:
Problem:
I don't actually mind the image artifacts which can be seen in the "unxor" window.

## Question

My question is actually about "xor":
The "xor" output obviously has biases that indicate the bitwise_xor and the mat type images are not doing what I expect them to.

If I had to guess: I would say that the max intensity pixels are creating biases where a xor is not producing the desired effect? **I'm not sure if there is a manipulation I can do using color depth or an operation on the mat type images to get the desired outcome**(impractical-key-management-but-as-secure-as-the-prng-is-image-obfuscation).

If anyone with experience in OpenCV can give me some guidance on what options are available to me or point out what I am overlooking it would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

A. Breuer

## Source Code

```
#include <cv.hpp> //necessary because this code uses the OpenCV library
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp" //necessary because this code uses the OpenCV library

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
// /* for the purpose of exiting via keyboard input////////////////////////////////////////////////
bool loop = true;
Size size(320,240);//the dst image size,e.g.100x100
// /* for the purpose of exiting via keyboard input////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* storage(memory allocation) for images and data///////////////////////////////////////////////
Mat image, random;
// */ storage for images and data//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* declaration of char to hold input from the keyboard buffer///////////////////////////////////
char KeyStroke;
// */ declaration of char to hold input from the keyboard buffer///////////////////////////////////

//prepare image source/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
VideoCapture cap;//assigning camera and proportions
cap.open(0);//starting webcam feed
//prepare image source/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

/* video input specific////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//cap.set(3, 320);
//cap.set(4, 240);
//cap.set(5,5);
//cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,320);
//cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,240);
*/// video input specific//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

namedWindow("original",1);//creating window for unmodified image
namedWindow("random",1);//creating window for "random noise"
namedWindow("xor",1);//creating window for obfuscated output
namedWindow("unxor",1);//creating window for deobfuscated image



while(loop == true)
{

try
{

// /* //read "image" from webcam or video//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        cap>>image;
// */ //read "image" from webcam or video//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //generate Mat full of random noise//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
        random = Mat(240, 320, CV_8UC3);
        randu(random, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255));
// */ //generate Mat full of random noise//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //resize image///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
resize(image,image,size);//resize image
// */ //resize image///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //recycled code//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
KeyStroke = cvWaitKey(100); //get keyboard input

        if(KeyStroke==' '){
            break;
        }
// */ //recycled code//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //placeholder creation///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
Mat imageT, randomT, image2; //placeholders to preserve "image" and "random" in their original conditions for comparison
vector<Mat> channels; //bitwise_xor placeholder for "imageT"
vector<Mat> channels2; //bitwise_xor placeholder for "randomT"
vector<Mat> channels3; //bitwise_xor placeholder for "image2"
// */ //placeholder creation///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //prepare the input Mat(s) for bitwise_xor processing////////////////////////////////////////
cvtColor(image, imageT, CV_BGR2HSV);//cvtColor conversion of "image"(type: Mat) to HSV colorspace "imageT"(type: Mat)
cvtColor(random, randomT, CV_BGR2HSV);//cvtColor conversion of "random"(type: Mat) to HSV colorspace "randomT"(type: Mat)
cvtColor(image, image2, CV_BGR2HSV);//cvtColor conversion of "image"(type: Mat) to HSV colorspace "image2"(type: Mat)
// */ //prepare the input Mat(s) for bitwise_xor processing////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for adding the "random noise" to the output//////////////
split(imageT, channels);
Mat HueI(channels[0]); //Create "Hue" channel
Mat SatI(channels[1]); //Create "Sat" channel
Mat VeeI(channels[2]); //Create "Vee" channel
// */ //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for adding the "random noise" to the output//////////////


// /* //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for adding the "random noise" to the output//////////////
split(randomT, channels2);
Mat HueR(channels2[0]); //Create "Hue" channel
Mat SatR(channels2[1]); //Create "Sat" channel
Mat VeeR(channels2[2]); //Create "Vee" channel
// */ //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for adding the "random noise" to the output//////////////


// /* //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for holding the output from xor//////////////////////////
split(image2, channels3);
Mat Hue2(channels3[0]); //Create "Hue" channel
Mat Sat2(channels3[1]); //Create "Sat" channel
Mat Vee2(channels3[2]); //Create "Vee" channel
// */ //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for holding the output from xor//////////////////////////

// /* //xor "random noise" with the input mat to obfuscate the image from its original appearance//
bitwise_xor(HueI, HueR, Hue2);//xor "HueI"(type: Mat) from "channels[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "imageT" split() output] with "HueR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]
bitwise_xor(SatI, SatR, Sat2);//xor "SatI"(type: Mat) from "channels[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "imageT" split() output] with "SatR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[1]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]
bitwise_xor(VeeI, VeeR, Vee2);//xor "VeeI"(type: Mat) from "channels[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "imageT" split() output] with "VeeR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[2]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]
// */ //xor "random noise" with the input mat to obfuscate the image from its original appearance//

// /* //show the obfuscated output in window "xor"/////////////////////////////////////////////////
merge(channels3, image2);
cvtColor(image2, image2, CV_HSV2BGR);//GPU namespace cvtColor conversion of "oclImage"(type: Mat) to HSV colorspace "oclSrc_hsv"(type: Mat)
imshow("xor",image2);//show the obfuscated output in window "xor"
// */ //show the obfuscated output in window "xor"/////////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //prepare the obfuscated output for removal of the "random noise"////////////////////////////
cvtColor(image2, image2, CV_BGR2HSV);//cvtColor conversion of "image2"(type: Mat) to HSV colorspace "image2"(type: Mat)
// */ //prepare the obfuscated output for removal of the "random noise"////////////////////////////

// /* //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for removing the "random noise" from the output//////////
split(image2, channels3);

Mat Hue3(channels3[0]); //Create "Hue" channel
Mat Sat3(channels3[1]); //Create "Sat" channel
Mat Vee3(channels3[2]); //Create "Vee" channel
// */ //prepare the necessary vector<mat> for removing the "random noise" from the output//////////

// /* //xor same "random noise" with the output mat to return the image to its original appearance/
bitwise_xor(Hue3, HueR, Hue3);//xor "Hue3"(type: Mat) from "channels3[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "image2" split() output] with "HueR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[0]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]

bitwise_xor(Sat3, SatR, Sat3);//xor "Sat3"(type: Mat) from "channels3[1]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "image2" split() output] with "SatR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[1]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]

bitwise_xor(Vee3, VeeR, Vee3);//xor "Vee3"(type: Mat) from "channels3[2]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "image2" split() output] with "VeeR"(type: Mat)<-from "channels2[1]"(type: vector<Mat>)<-[composed of "randomT" split() output]
// /* //xor same "random noise" with the output mat to return the image to its original appearance/

// /* //show the deobfuscated output in window "unxor"/////////////////////////////////////////////
merge(channels3, image2); //recombine the 3x HSV Channels of "channel3"(type: vector<Mat>) into "image2"(type: Mat)
cvtColor(image2, image2, CV_HSV2BGR);//cvtColor conversion of "image2"(type: Mat) to BGR colorspace "image2"(type: Mat)
imshow("unxor",image2);//normal window show webcam or video
// */ //show the deobfuscated output in window "unxor"/////////////////////////////////////////////

// /* //show the original input in window "original" and "random noise" in window "random"/////////
cvtColor(imageT, image, CV_HSV2BGR);//cvtColor conversion of "randomT"(type: Mat) to BGR colorspace "random"(type: Mat)
cvtColor(randomT, random, CV_HSV2BGR);//cvtColor conversion of "randomT"(type: Mat) to BGR colorspace "random"(type: Mat)
imshow("original",image);//normal window show webcam or video
imshow("random",random);//normal window show webcam or video
// /* //show the original input in window "original" and "random noise" in window "random"/////////
}

// /* //recycled code//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
catch (Exception& e)//error checking
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
}

char key = waitKey(33) & 0xFF;//checking for key press
if (key == 'q')//press q to quit
        {
                //cap.release();
                image.release();
                loop = false;
        }
// */ //recycled code///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm not sure exactly what you want. Do you want to get rid of the artifacts in the `unxor`-output?

Comment: Thanks, and sorry about the wall-o-text. I'm trying to do the image equivalent of a "one time pad". I'm trying to make the output mat displayed in "xor" look visually/cryptographically indistinguishable from a random noise mat like the one displayed in "random"(while preserving the original data if the random noise key is subtracted from the image). If the code were working properly, the "xor" window should not have light/dark regions with discernible edges. If executed correctly, I believe the color histogram should be nearly uniform and average brightness should be approx. 1/2 the range.

Answer (score 1):

https://i.stack.imgur.com/s4aZW.jpg

I think I've got a working solution now:

```
#include <cv.hpp>
#include "/usr/local/include/opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

bool loop = true;
Size size(320,240);

Mat image, image0, random;

char KeyStroke;

VideoCapture cap;
cap.open(0);

namedWindow("original",1);
namedWindow("random",1);
namedWindow("xor",1);
namedWindow("unxor",1);

while(loop == true)
{

try
{
cap>>image0;

random = Mat(240,320, CV_8UC3); //source: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html
randu(random, Scalar::all(0), Scalar::all(255)); //source: http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/mat_the_basic_image_container/mat_the_basic_image_container.html
imshow("random",random);

KeyStroke = cvWaitKey(100);

if(KeyStroke==' ')
{
  break;
}

vector<Mat> channels0;
vector<Mat> channels1;
vector<Mat> channels2;
vector<Mat> channels3;

Mat imageT, imageD;
imageT = Mat::zeros(240,320, CV_8UC3);
imageD = Mat::zeros(240,320, CV_8UC3);
resize(image0,image0,size,CV_INTER_NN);

image = image0;

split(image, channels0);
Mat BlueI(channels0[0]);
Mat GreenI(channels0[1]);
Mat RedI(channels0[2]);

split(random, channels1);
Mat BlueR(channels1[0]);
Mat GreenR(channels1[1]);
Mat RedR(channels1[2]);

split(imageT, channels2);
Mat Blue2(channels2[0]);
Mat Green2(channels2[1]);
Mat Red2(channels2[2]);

split(imageD, channels3);
Mat Blue3(channels3[0]);
Mat Green3(channels3[1]);
Mat Red3(channels3[2]);

bitwise_xor(BlueI, BlueR, Blue2);
bitwise_xor(GreenI, GreenR, Green2);
bitwise_xor(RedI, RedR, Red2);
merge(channels2, imageT);

bitwise_xor(Blue2, BlueR, Blue3);
bitwise_xor(Green2, GreenR, Green3);
bitwise_xor(Red2, RedR, Red3);
merge(channels3, imageD);

merge(channels2, imageT);
merge(channels1, random);
merge(channels0, image);

imshow("original",image0);
resize(imageT,imageT,size, CV_INTER_NN);
imshow("xor",imageT);
resize(imageD,imageD,size, CV_INTER_NN);
imshow("unxor",imageD);

}
catch (Exception& e)
{
    const char* err_msg = e.what();
    std::cout << "exception caught: imshow:\n" << err_msg << std::endl;
}

char key = waitKey(33) & 0xFF;
if (key == 'q')
        {
                image.release();
                loop = false;
        }
}
return 0;
}
```

I think it was the HSV Color Space that was causing problems. Once I switched back to using BGR everything started working fine. I realized something fishy was going on when I did a visualization of the random noise Mat and noticed 2 of the 3 channels were not behaving as expected. http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_calculation/histogram_calculation.html